How do you construct a While loop using propositional dynamic logic?
I am learning some modal logic from a textbook (Modal Logic from Blackburn, De Rijke and Venema) and they have an example about propositional dynamic logic (PDL). Here they explain that if $\pi$ is a program, then $\pi^*$ is also a program, and $\pi^*$ is an iteration of $\pi$ for a finite (possibly zero) number of times.
They give some examples of formulae using the modal operator associated with this, $\langle\pi^*\rangle$, which I think I understand.
One of the questions they pose is: How do you construct a While loop using PDL (of the form: while $\Phi$ perform $\pi$). I couldn't figure this out, and online I found a construction using $(\Phi?;\pi)^*$. The interpretation I can think of for this would be something like: "Check if $\Phi$ is true, and if so, excecute $\pi$. Keep doing this until $\Phi$ isn't true". (Obviously here I'm influenced by the fact that I expect it to be a While loop).
What I don't understand is the role of the $*$ here. In the definition they give, it just seems to suggest a random or non-specified number of iterations (and this seems to be supported by the other formulae they gave using the modal operators), but in the given While construction the $*$ seems to be doing basically all the heavy lifting.
I'd love to hear whether this construction of the While loop is correct, whether I interpret it correctly and how I should understand the role of the $*$.
Many thanks,
Hugo

As written, $(\Phi ?;\pi)^*$ only repeats checking $\Phi$ and executing $\pi$ some nondeterministic finite number of times, and relates states $(x, y)$ even if $\Phi$ is true in $y$.
What we want is to ensure we only end up in states where $\Phi$ is false, so se need to sequence a check for that, and we get the program for while Phi: pi:
$(\Phi?;\pi)^*;\lnot\Phi?$
This is "repeat checking $\Phi$ and if true execute $\pi$ some finite number of times, then ensure $\Phi$ is false"

Thank you for your answer! Could you explain what happens in the case that $\neg\Phi?$ fails? (i.e. We have repeated the checking and executing $\pi$ some finite number of times but $\Phi$ is still true). Is that where a "loop" occurs? Are we then "sent back" to the program $(\Phi?;\pi)^$, and if so, why is the $$ needed at all? What would the interpretation of the program $(\Phi?;\pi);\neg\Phi?$ be?

Essentially, the "repeat" part is nondeterministic, you can think of it as giving a result for all nonnegative integers $n$ as the number of repetitions, but the last part essentiallly filters out those $n$ or which $\Phi$ is true after $n$ repetitions.
